# Using Logger.Log to log different value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, stackdriver

I was wondering: is it even possible to use `Logger.Log` in Google Apps Script to log different string to be posted to a spreadsheet?

I have the following code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("spreadsheet url");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("spreadsheet sheet");
var DocNumber = e.parameter.DocNumber;
  var folderId = "Folder ID 1";
  var lastFileUrl = getLatestFile(folderId); // just a function that retrieves url of latest file in the folder

  Logger.log(lastFileUrl);

  var addUrl = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var fileURL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+lastFileUrl;


  var folderId2 = "Folder ID 2";
  var lastFileUrl2 = getLatestFile(folderId2); // same as above

  Logger.log(lastFileUrl2);

  var addUrl2 = sheet.getRange(1,3,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var fileURL2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+lastFileUrl2;


sheet.appendRow([DocNumber,fileURL,fileURL2]);

}
```

When this get posted to the spreadsheet, it only posts the second url (fileURL2) - I assume because the last value in the log is this. But I was hoping to post both URL into the spreadsheet.

I tried setting it as a var first as well:

```
var URL2 = Logger.log(lastFileURL2);
```

but then the posted value will be `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=Logger`

I also tried using appendRow before the second URL logging but it still only takes the second url and disregard the first url.

Therefore, I was curios whether this is even possible at all?

And if not, what's the best way to achieve this without using `Logger.log`?

Spreadsheet output:

[image: sheet structure]

`URL1` and `URL2` is the URL from Google Drive folder.
Also, forgot to mention, I'm using the script as a Web App, used by an android app. Posting files into the Drive folder is okay, the only problem is fetching the links of the files in different folders.

These are the codes I used to get the latest file url from my folders:

```
function getLatestFile(folderId) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_1_ID").getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].id;
}


function getLatestFile(folderId2) {
  var files2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_2_ID").getFiles();
  var fileObj2 = [];
  while (files2.hasNext()) {
    var file2 = files2.next();
    fileObj2.push({id: file2.getId(), date: file2.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj2.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj2[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Re: `=Logger` of course it will - take a look at what [`log` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata) call returns

Comment: Also: what are `addUrl` and `addUrl2` used for - they seem to have not being referenced by anything else? Please, post a screenshot of what the output looks like (don't share the spreadsheet, please) And it would help if you added the code for `getLatestFile` (in the question)

Comment: Added the picture

Comment: Thanks - does not seem like there should be an issue - my only guess as of now is that `getLatestFile` returns the same URL for both files, that there is a problem with its logic. Could you update the question with the code from it?

Comment: Ah, here we go - function names have to unique. The best case is that `getLatestFile` gets called with the second code, the worst - the result is indeterministic

Comment: Updated it, so you are saying it is possible to use ```Logger.log``` to log two different string?

Comment: Of course it is) You have a problem with duplicating the same function. Make `Folder_2_ID` a parameter (you already did, but for some reason don't use - `folderId`). Then, scrap the second function - and voila

Comment: Wow, how did I not noticed that I didn't change my function name. Jeez. Thanks a lot ! It was a real head-scratcher for me !

Comment: No problem, but you should definitely get rid of the second one - they are the same, just reuse the first one - I will add an answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Having two functions declared under the same name

**Solution**

Step by step:

1. Remove one of the functions (they are identical in terms in usage)
2. Make the remaining one use the parameter passed in it:

```
function getLatestFile(folderId) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].id;
}
```

3. Change `Logger` to `console` - as of recently, all logs are sent to Stackdriver service, and thus there is no benefit in using `Logger` (besides by using `console` you make script more portable).

**Commentary**

What happens when you declare two or more functions under same name? Normally, the last one declared gets executed (basically, second declaration overwrites the first):

```js
function clone(original) {
  return `I am the clone of ${original}`;
}

function clone(cloned) {
  return `I am a clone of ${cloned}'s clone`;
}

const elem = document.querySelector("#cloned");
elem.textContent = clone("Gary");
```

```html
<h2 id="cloned"></h2>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Saved me from a lot of troubles, I almost gave up, thinking it was impossible.

Comment: My pleasure! When you think that your code should definitely work, but it does not - always check if the naming is correct, execution reaches the desired point, etc, etc. Btw, you can use the built-in debugger to test what exactly happens at each step